# Preprocessing Info.plist in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, info.plist

I'm trying to use Info.plist preprocessing available in Xcode so that I can embed the latest git commit id in the app's Info.plist.  It works fine in Xcode 3 using the technique described here: http://www.cimgf.com/2011/02/20/revisiting-git-tags-and-building/ However, when I try it in Xcode 4 it looks like no preprocessing is performed after the first build.

What I see:

- Starting from a clean slate when building my target, InfoPlist.h is created with the correct contents, target builds and runs successfully, and I can access the value at runtime.
- Create a new commit to change the HEAD commit id.
- Build my target again, InfoPlist.h is updated to have the new commit id, target builds and runs successfully, however, the value in the info dictionary is the previous commit id.

It looks like Xcode is running the script build step, but not preprocessing my Info.plist, it's using a cached version.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?

I tried removing InfoPlist.h as a post build step so that it would always be a newly modified file, but it didn't make a difference.

**Update:**
Performing a clean, then building again causes the correct value to appear.  However, I shouldn't have to clean my target every time I make a commit.

Comment: I am still seeing this behavior in XCode 4.5.2. 

Did you ever find a fix or a better workaround than cleaning each time?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com). I think this is a bug.

As a work-around until then, you might try editing your scheme, selecting the Build action, expanding its disclosure triangle, then adding a **Pre**-action Script that runs `touch` against the PLIST file. That should fix it for now.

Comment: I'll open a bug.  Unfortunately, `touch`ing the file didn't help.  The file already gets modified by script phase of the dependency target.

Comment: Definitely a pretty nasty bug, then. :-( That will affect several upcoming releases of my own stuff, so thanks for bringing it to light.

Answer (score 0):

If your script is in an Aggregate Target and implemented as a Target Dependency, this should work without cleaning the project:

```
plist=${PROJECT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}-Info.plist

touch $plist
```